# Bind JSON data to row in table MVC 4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, rest

I need help with framing the code in the Controller to bind the JSON data to rows in a table. Below is the code for Controller

```
var jsonString = "{\"roleMappings\":[{\"user\":{\"id\":\"4b147d87-64eb-4049-bbd3-ade96d18af89\",\"name\":\"PFRENC17\",\"actualName\":\"French, Phil (P.)\",\"displayName\":\"French, Phil (P.) (PFRENC17)\",\"email\":\"pfrenc17@abc.com\",\"deleted\":false,\"deletedDate\":0,\"authenticationRealm\":\"f4191d4b-4331-4637-af6f-c89781687bf6\",\"isLockedOut\":false,\"lastLoginDate\":1502803623890,\"isDeletable\":true},\"role\":{\"id\":\"3de854ce-34ed-4b7f-9b99-9fdf04c0345c\",\"name\":\"Developer\",\"description\":\"Application Developer\",\"isDeletable\":true}},{\"user\":{\"id\":\"3afd930e-9608-4257-a962-0a82b792a6e9\",\"name\":\"RSIEGLE3\",\"actualName\":\"Siegler, Ryan (R.)\",\"displayName\":\"Siegler, Ryan (R.) (RSIEGLE3)\",\"email\":\"rsiegle3@abc.com\",\"deleted\":false,\"deletedDate\":0,\"authenticationRealm\":\"f4191d4b-4331-4637-af6f-c89781687bf6\",\"isLockedOut\":false,\"lastLoginDate\":1500300166062,\"isDeletable\":true},\"role\":{\"id\":\"3de854ce-34ed-4b7f-9b99-9fdf04c0345c\",\"name\":\"Developer\",\"description\":\"Application Developer\",\"isDeletable\":true}},{\"user\":{\"id\":\"33dd9fea-4685-4505-91ba-5c0508301b56\",\"name\":\"yyang4\",\"actualName\":\"Yang, Yvonne (Y.)\",\"displayName\":\"Yang, Yvonne (Y.) (yyang4)\",\"email\":\"yyang4@abc.com\",\"deleted\":false,\"deletedDate\":0,\"authenticationRealm\":\"f4191d4b-4331-4637-af6f-c89781687bf6\",\"isLockedOut\":false,\"lastLoginDate\":1522249840141,\"isDeletable\":true},\"role\":{\"id\":\"f722b338-01c1-43cb-bc53-853cfb0d2249\",\"name\":\"UC Auto Discovery\",\"description\":\"\",\"isDeletable\":false}},{\"user\":{\"id\":\"33dd9fea-4685-4505-91ba-5c0508301b56\",\"name\":\"yyang4\",\"actualName\":\"Yang, Yvonne (Y.)\",\"displayName\":\"Yang, Yvonne (Y.) (yyang4)\",\"email\":\"yyang4@abc.com\",\"deleted\":false,\"deletedDate\":0,\"authenticationRealm\":\"f4191d4b-4331-4637-af6f-c89781687bf6\",\"isLockedOut\":false,\"lastLoginDate\":1522249840141,\"isDeletable\":true},\"role\":{\"id\":\"8421e59e-ce5f-477b-aa6f-0313aa1223e6\",\"name\":\"Application_Lead\",\"description\":\"Development Team Lead\",\"isDeletable\":true}},{\"user\":{\"id\":\"5599437f-68f9-4c20-bd0a-5c26d55628e1\",\"name\":\"UBLDUCD1\",\"actualName\":\"Blducd1, U (U.)\",\"displayName\":\"Blducd1, U (U.) (UBLDUCD1)\",\"deleted\":false,\"deletedDate\":0,\"authenticationRealm\":\"f4191d4b-4331-4637-af6f-c89781687bf6\",\"isLockedOut\":false,\"lastLoginDate\":1515694447960,\"isDeletable\":true},\"role\":{\"id\":\"8421e59e-ce5f-477b-aa6f-0313aa1223e6\",\"name\":\"Application_Lead\",\"description\":\"Development Team Lead\",\"isDeletable\":true}},{\"group\":{\"id\":\"7862c275-8eb2-42cf-895c-214c2826a0b8\",\"name\":\"config_viewer\",\"enabled\":true},\"role\":{\"id\":\"ba4cdbf1-6b97-436f-9b40-a7e21d8394f2\",\"name\":\"ReadOnly\",\"description\":\"Read-only access\",\"isDeletable\":true}}],\"id\":\"877eb9b9-6dd9-432d-b55a-01bd406d039a\",\"name\":\"AftImport Team\",\"isDeletable\":true}";
                JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string,User>> rows = (List<Dictionary<string,User>>)javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(Dictionary<string,User>));
                foreach (Dictionary<string,User> teams in rows)
                {
                    rows = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach(DataColumn col in column)
                    row.add();
                }
```

Below is code for View

```
<table border="1" align="center" style="font-family:Arial; width:900px;">
        <tr height="50">
            <th>Member</th> <th>Roles</th> <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr height="30">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th><button class="editbtn">Delete User</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="editbtn">Change Role</button></th>
        </tr>
        <tr height="30">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr height="30">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

I need help with binding the "name:PFRENC17" field with "Member" in View.So I would be able to display all names in the Members rows in the table.

Comment: Do you want to do that binding server side or client side?

Comment: Server side. I am going to host the ASP.NET application on IIS

Comment: Please can someone assist me with the code to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

Given you want to do this server side, this is a simple case of using the Razor view engine. For instance:

Models:

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Dictionary<string, User>

<table border="1" align="center" style="font-family:Arial; width:900px;">
    <tr height="50">
        <th>Member</th>
        <th>Roles</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var user in Model.Select(x => x.Value))
    {
        <tr height="30">
            <th>@user.DisplayName</th>
            <th>@user.Role.Name</th>
            <th><button class="editbtn">Delete User</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="editbtn">Change Role</button></th>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Could you share about the code in the Controller because when I tried implementing the above code. It shows me error at @foreach (var user in Model.Select(x => x.Value))